# How to print no of pending tuples realtime

Tags: apache-storm

I am running many parallel requests in my storm topology and have set topology.max.spout.pending = 100. Some of my requests are timing out (not a  storm tuple timeout but explicit timeout set by my application for ach request). I am using anchored tuples so they are expected to be acked. Now I suspect at some point, # of pending tuples reaches topology.max.spout.pending and this causes other requests to wait. How can I print no of pending tuples at realtime?